# Jquery Jtable add merged column headers

Tags: jquery, header, jtable, html-table

I am trying to use Jquery Jtable plugin 
and I need Merged column headers, for the view to be as follows

```
+----+------+------+------+------+
|    |     H2      |     H3      |
+ H1 +------+------+------+------+
|    |  C1  |  C2  |  C3  |  C4  |
+----+------+------+------+------+
```

WITH DATA TO BE POPULATED UNDER H1,C1,C2,C3,C4

Please help.

Manish B

Comment: Have you tried anything? Could you provide some code if you did?

Comment: Thought of re-writing thead after the table is loaded, but it shall be a unnecessary server query when loading for the first time, when using a filter (user input ) for fetching records